# Can one use an example that includes high degree of profanity?

Tags: discussion

I encountered this situation when answering [this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/12719/is-a-filled-hole-still-a-hole/15187#15187) question. I could make a much more convincing argument if I used one high profanity example. (And I don't know if I can use that example as an example on meta to get you people more clear idea). Some hints are,

1. As the question was about nature of holes, example contained a hole.
2. Involving a type a sexual intercourse some people consider unnatural.

I hope you see where I am going. If not and if the rules allow, ask me, Ill explain in edit/comments.

Comment: Please read the referenced question and my answer to fully get the idea

Comment: Reason for downvote please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Profanity" might be quite difficult to tie down effectively, but I think it's possible to discuss human sexuality, even in some of its less socially accepted forms, without being profane about it.  If you want to talk about what I think you want to talk about then you certainly could do, but there's a question about whether it is the best example of the case you're trying to make or whether you're partly using it as an example for shock value.

The profanity would come from treating the example in a flippant or off-hand manner, as though it wasn't a very particular and private case, and that is very much **not** to be encouraged.  With sexuality in particular, however, give it its due consideration and respect, and if it's still a good enough example to warrant giving it as an answer to a question asked in all good faith then do so, doing your best to retain dignity as much as you can.